# Is it a problem to have different sonames of same library installed at the same time?

Tags: package-management

Say you add a PPA and upgrade packages. Is it a problem to have different sonames of libraries such as libavdevice and libavcodec installed at the same time?

Comment: If packages are upgraded, then you won't have two versions, but only the new upgraded one. With two different versions installed, yes, there might be problems.

Comment: @mikewhatever No, after adding `ppa:sergey-dryabzhinsky/ffmpeg` in Bionic and upgrading I have a few duplicate libraries installed that differ by their soname.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently Ubuntu inherits the Debian policies.

[Debian Library Packaging guide](https://www.netfort.gr.jp/%7Edancer/column/libpkg-guide/libpkg-guide.html#debiantrait) tells:

> From the point of a single distribution all packages should use the same version to reduce the number of installed packages and increase the possibility of sharing loaded libraries. And from the viewpoint of a distribution which can be upgraded, several different incompatible versions of shared libraries should be able to coexist.

[Debian Library Packaging guide](https://www.netfort.gr.jp/%7Edancer/column/libpkg-guide/libpkg-guide.html#sonameapiabi) tells:

> If a new version of a library package breaks a currently existing and working package (the ABI), the SONAME version number should be bumped up, or the change be reverted, or both. By bumping up the SONAME version number, the old binaries which used to link to the old version of the library should be able to run with the old library, and the new and the old libraries can coexist.